# safe for each variable in template =? autoescape off for whole template

Tags: python, django

Does the use of `|safe` to each variable in the template application and each text equivalent to `{% autoestsape off %}` the whole template?

If not then when it may exploitable?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `filter` tag to apply a filter to a whole part of your template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#filter

Comment: Thx, i know it. But the question was slightly different if the entire template be wrapped in filter safe is it the same as autoestsape off?

Comment: Also from django docs for `filter` tag:

The `escape` and `safe` filters are not acceptable arguments. Instead, use the autoescape tag to manage autoescaping for blocks of template code.